# Checkbox dynamic ID send to PHP file without page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, html, checkbox

I am very close with this but struggling to get my dynamic php and Javascript to work together. Heres where I'm up too.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    function exefunction(id){

    if (document.getElementById(id).checked == true) {
        // Create our XMLHttpRequest object
        var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        // Create some variables we need to send to our PHP file
        var url = "update.php";
        var id = document.getElementById(id).value 
        var check = 1;
        var vars = "id="+id+"&check="+check;
        hr.open("POST", url, true);
        // Set content type header information for sending url encoded variables in the request
        hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        // Access the onreadystatechange event for the XMLHttpRequest object
        hr.send(vars); // Actually execute the request
    }

                    else if (document.getElementById(id).checked == false){
                        // Create our XMLHttpRequest object
        var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        // Create some variables we need to send to our PHP file
        var url = "update.php";
        var id = document.getElementById(id).value 
        var check = 0;
        var vars = "id="+id+"&check="+check;
        hr.open("POST", url, true);
        // Set content type header information for sending url encoded variables in the request
        hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        // Access the onreadystatechange event for the XMLHttpRequest object
        hr.send(vars); // Actually execute the request

                }
            </script>
```

My php checks the database and will auto check the tick boxes accordingly:

```
if ($checkboxone == 1){
$Trans .='<td width="60">
<input id="'.$id.'" type="checkbox" onClick="exefunction(this.id)" value="'.$id.'" checked /></td>'; 
}else{
$Trans .='<td width="60"><input id="'.$id.'" type="checkbox" onClick="exefunction(this.id);" value="'.$id.'" /></td>'; 
}
```

What I need it to do is when a tick box is checked or unchecked it updates my database the issue I'm having is passing the unique id of the checkbox through my javascript. The javascript works if I put the id in and have one checkbox.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: This is tagged with jquery, why?

Comment: You could be using jQuery UI's `sortable.serialize()` to do this quite easily.